# Unable to upload images as Django admin

Tags: python-3.x, django, postgresql, django-models, django-views

This is the models.py code to  define the field type and to accept the input of type image

#### models.py

```
car_photo_1 = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d')
car_photo_2 = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d', blank=True)
```

#### settings.py

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

#### urls.py of (project)

```
urlpatterns [
   ....
   ....

]+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

but when I run the program and click on upload image for car_photo_1 the upload option is greyed out so I'm unable to save the input. Can someone assist on how to proceed here?

Comment: share views.py, models.py and template which display image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check bellow necessary settings for the image handle in Django

### Add Code in Project (urls.py)

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,include

from django.conf import settings # --------> this
from django.conf.urls.static import static # --------> this

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('myapp.urls')),
]+static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT) # --------> this
```

### Add Code in Project (setting.py)

```
MEDIA_ROOT =  os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media') 
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```